# Assign a macro Name toi a button based off cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I have a workbook that copies and moves on sheet to a new workbook and saves it to a selected destination. I have saved code into that sheet so that it carries over to the new workbook. I need to code so that It will assign the macro name to a shape in the workbook.

So the code before editing looks like this:

```
    Selection.OnAction = "Sheet17.PEER_REVIEW_COMPLETED"
```

The issue is that if someone adds a sheet to the workbook that moved sheet is no longer sheet 17. So, I created a formula in a cell that spits out `"Sheet17.PEER_REVIEW_COMPLETED"` but the 17 automatically changes based on how many sheets there are. How do I assign the `Selection.OnAction` to reference that cell?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to embed your reference to the cell in a separate macro. For example if your macro name is contained in the range name below:

```
Public Sub runtest()

Application.Run Sheet2.Range("D14").Value

End Sub
```

Your Selection.OnAction value can instead be

```
Selection.OnAction = "runtest"
```

I'm not sure if there's a more direct way of doing this or if there are any downsides to doing it this way, but I've just tried it and this way does seem to work

Comment: The problem is when I Copy the worksheet to a new book the macros stored in the current workbook do not move over. The only code that moves over to the new workbook is the code embedded into the sheet. The problem with the embedded code is that it needs to have the sheet number before it. The name of the actual sheet is always the same though, maybe there is a way to call it by the actual sheet name?

Comment: @Bhiggz the embedded code doesn't need to have the sheet number in it - you said you'd created a formula in a cell which gives you the sheet number and the macro name. What the code above allows you to do is to run the macro defined in that cell. The macro "runtest" runs whichever macro is named in Sheet2 Cell D14 (modify as needed) - where this needs to be your cell with the formula in it that outputs "Sheet17.PEER_REVIEW_COMPLETED".

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying the worksheet using the `worksheet.Copy` or `Worksheet.Move` methods, you can immediately get a handle to the code module name of the copied sheet.

Example:

```
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Set destWB = Workbooks.Open("...")
    ' ...
    Sheet17.Move After:=destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count)
    Dim codeName As String: codeName = destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count).CodeName
    Debug.Print codeName
    '...
    myShape.OnAction = codeName & ".PEER_REVIE"
```

Comment: Is there a way to just assign the button to call the code embedded into the active sheet?

Comment: The `ActiveSheet` is usually the one you have just `Move`d or `Copy`d, so you could use `codeName = ActiveSheet.CodeName`. But counting on it is not good practice and not robust! Using explicit references is much better. :)

Comment: Do you mean that you want the code to stay in the original workbook?